# NServicebus: can I have message rollback without DTC?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

As far as I understand NServicebus works in this way - it wraps all database transactions together with message transaction using DTC and in case of failure, rolls everything back.

Now, I don't need, that NServicebus would handle my database transactions - I'll take care of them by my self - because I don't wish to use DTC (nservicebushost and sql server are on separate ec2 instances, and I think I can't open RPC port on ec2 instances), but I don't wish to loose messages in case handling would fail - in case of exception, I would like to have retry and after max retries message to be moved to error queue.

Can I configure Nservicebus to behave like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here has to do with crashes of your ec2 instances. The DTC guarantees that messages won't be lost even in the case of a crash.

The other option is to suppress the ambient transaction in your handler:

`using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))`

In 3.0 we'll introduce a way to have this done in NServiceBus itself. It'll probably be a call to .SuppressDTC() (or something like that) in your fluent initialization code.

Comment: I understand that, but I would prefer to have alternatives. Let's say I had own messaging implementation and was doing it different - I was peeking for message, trying to process it and if processing was successfull - receive message from queue, so that was as reliable as using transactions, although it had drawback - it would not work in multithreaded scenario, but if I know that I'm running in single thread (and I know it, because I'm using non commercial nservicebus), I could use such mechanism to avoid DTC.